# How do I add a Google Cloud Endpoints Module to my Android project in IntelliJ?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to test out Google Cloud Endpoints with an Android project I have in IntelliJ. I use IntelliJ for a lot of stuff including:

- Web development.
- Writing Python scripts.
- Making Java command line programs.
- Playing with new languages I am considering learning like Rust.

I prefer to do this all in the same IDE because I have a lot of plugins for various things and a lot of custom settings and such. Point is I don't want to use Android Studio.

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ I can usually follow along with all the tutorials made for Android Studio in IntelliJ, although sometimes UI stuff is moved around a bit. However I don't seem to be able to find any way to add a Google Cloud Endpoints Module to my project in IntelliJ. I am trying to [follow this guide](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/add_module).

I installed the Google Cloud Tools plugin, but there doesn't seem to be any interface to access them. So does anyone know how to do this in plain old IntelliJ or is this maybe something that is only possible in Android Studio at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the TL of the Google Cloud plugins for IntelliJ and Android Studio.

Unfortunately the App Engine module generation features from Android Studio aren't available in IntelliJ.  There are some platform differences that make porting that feature-set non-trivial. Eventually we want to bring our Android/Cloud integration to all IntelliJ platform users, but for now we are focused on Cloud only support (think Stackdriver Debugger, App Engine flex and standard deployment, Cloud Repository integration) in IntelliJ.